# Big-O notaion for $2n^4 + \log_2n^8$

Tags: asymptotics

I need to find the best big-O for:

$$3n^4 + \log_2n^8$$
So I said:
$$3n^4 + \log_2n^8 = 3n^4 + 8\log_2n \leq 3n^4 + 8n$$
Therefore, the given function is $O(n^4)$ in the best case.

Is this correct?

Comment: a small editing advice: if you a / to $log_2$ then it looks like $\log_2$

Comment: @user190080 Gotcha, thanks -fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer is correct. Note, however, that if the $3n^4$ term was missing, your answer would be $\mathcal{O}(\log_2n)$, not $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: I think we can say that it would then be $O(\log_2n)$, right? (not $O(\log_2n^8$)).

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for the oversight